# Use XCOM Value In Operators

Tags: python, airflow

I want to use XCOM values as a parameter of my Operator.

Firstly, was executed OracleReadOperator, which read table from db, and return values.

This is value in XCOM:

```
[{'SOURCE_HOST': 'TEST_HOST'}]
```

Using this function I want to get value from xcom

```
def print_xcom(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='task1')
```

Then use values as as parameter:

```
with DAG(
        schedule_interval='@daily',
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=120),
        default_args=args,
        template_searchpath=tmpl_search_path,
        catchup=False,
        dag_id='test'
) as dag:
    
    test_l = OracleLoadOperator(
            task_id = "task1",
            oracle_conn_id="orcl_conn_id",
            object_name='table'
    )
    test_l
    
    def print_xcom(**kwargs):
        ti = kwargs['ti']
        ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='task1', value='TARGET_TABLE')


    
    
    load_from_db = MsSqlToOracleTransfer(
                task_id= 'task2',
                mssql_conn_id = "{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='task1') }",
                oracle_conn_id = 'conn_def_orc',
                sql= 'test.sql',
                oracle_table = "oracle_table"
        tasks.append(load_from_db)
```

I don't know do I need print_xcom function.
Or I can get value without it, if yes how?
I got this error:

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowNotFoundException: The conn_id `{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='task1') }` isn't defined
```

Comment: The code isn't very clear. How the print_xcom relates to `MsSqlToOracleTransfer` ?

Comment: @Elad is it ok, now?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>To resolve the immediate `NameError` exception, Jinja expressions are strings so the arg for `oracle_table` needs to be updated to:</strike>

```py
oracle_table = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='print_xcom', key='task1') }}"
```

### EDIT

(Since the question and problem changed.)

Only `template_fields` declared for an operator can use Jinja expressions. It looks like `MsSqlToOracleTransfer` is a custom operator and if you want to use a Jinja template for the `mssql_conn_id` arg, it needs to be declared as part of `template_fields` otherwise the *literal string* is used as the arg value (which is what you're seeing).  Also you need the expression in the `"{{ ... }}"` format as well.

[Here is some guidance](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#templating) on Jinja templating with custom operators if you find it helpful.

However, it seems like there is more to this picture than what we have context for.  What is `task1`? Are you simply trying to retrieve a connection ID? What is it exactly you are trying to *accomplish* accessing `XComs` in the DAG?

Comment: I edited my question. Forgot my main problem.

Comment: It is just an example. In real case I want to use in many params.
I have a table with parameters where there is mssql_conn_id, sql, oracle_table. And I want that Operator take it from the table itself.(To solve it I used xcom)

Comment: Did the answer help at all though?

Answer (score 0):

The Airflow tasks has implemented the output attribute that returns an intance of XComArs. For example:

```
def push_xcom(ti):
    return {"key": "value"}


def pull_xcom(input):
    print(f'XCom: {input}')


with DAG(...) as dag:
    start = PythonOperator(task_id='dp_start', python_callable=push_xcom)
    
    end = PythonOperator(task_id='dp_start', python_callable=pull_xcom,
                         op_kwargs={'input': start.output})

    start >> end
```

Maybe you could use `test_l.output` in `load_from_db.mssql_conn_id`, But I think in the case of `whatever_conn_id parameters`, the value should be the ID of an Airflow connection.